# PMSM inductance in DQ domain

Tags: motor, inductor

The “abc <-> DQ” transformation matrix used for transforming currents, voltages and magnetic field
can they be used for transforming inductances also?
as given below-

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can... sort of.

Such a transform is VALID for current, voltage and flux.

From flux you can derive inductance which is related to the number of turns.

If I follow it through correctly: The 2phase equivalent should have 3/2 the number of turns as the three phase.

This would mean that a simple park-clark transformation of the stator phase inductance isn't enough to produce the equivalent 2phase representation, but it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

The three inductance La, Lb and Lc have been calculated (by maxwell) considering the magnet flux as well so your trafromation is good for Lq but not for Ld: for Ld you have to use the flux relation (Flux_d-Flux_magnet)/I_d

Comment: Hi there and welcome to EE.SE! You can improve your answer by formatting it, making it easier to read for everybody. It's very easy to do so on EE.SE and this link can be useful quick reference : https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5565/most-common-mathjax-uses-in-electrical-engineering